# How does this constant current circuit work?

Tags: power, analog, current-source, constant-current

I'm trying to develop a constant current source capable of **outputting 10mA regardless of impedance changes**. While I was looking into improved howland pumps as a potential solution, I came across this schematic which uses 3 amps (instead of 1). Any explanation into how this circuit works is appreciated. I'm also trying to figure out the purpose of the potentiometer (RV301 - looks more like a rheostat) in this circuit.

I'm still learning analog circuits so beginner friendly advice is appreciated. If this circuit seems inefficient, please tell me.

Here are the datasheets:

[DAC8831](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/dac8831)

[OPA277](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/opa277) -> Precision OpAmp

[INA149](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina149-ep.pdf?ts=1670474593884) -> Difference OpAmp

[OPA145](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa145.pdf?ts=1670555828040&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FOPA145) -> JFET OpAmp

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would probably be easier to follow if you used standard symbols for your op-amps and in-amps.

Comment: Any reason you can't use a normal constant current regulator set to 10mA?

Comment: Open to consider any option as long as it's [very] stable. I was experimenting with the LM317 initially, however, was advised against it by a mentor for unspecified reasons. Also need to be able to monitor the output current with significant accuracy.

Comment: What is "very" stable? What is "significant" accuracy? Engineering isn't just throwing words around; it's quantifying requirements so you can design a solution that fits them.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm still new to analog circuitry so forgive any buzzwords. Maybe a better word for stable would be tolerance- ideally, I want the 10mA output to be constant without significant tolerance (+/- 1% max).

Comment: I appreciate your feedback and will try to be more descriptive going forward.

Comment: Further to @Hearth’s comments - basically your schematic does not convey much information. It’s enough to route a pcb, but useless for a human to extract the circuit’s intent. If it was drawn in a conventional manner, the average engineer would be able to understand the circuit in an instant.

Comment: What impedances? After the replacement of the INA149 by an "equivalent" schematic, something is "strange" ... I don't see where is the current measurement (for feedback) into the load ...

Comment: The lm317 with it's 5% accuracy and 5mA of quiescent current is a poor choice for a 1% accurate, 10mA constant current source, but it's also 50 years old and obsolete. Building this out of discrete components would be educational, but if you want this to work I'd buy the 50 cent ldo designed for the job.

Comment: @user1850479 could I accomplish constant current with just an LDO? I came across this source - https://www.analog.com/en/design-notes/using-a-linear-regulator-to-produce-a-constant-current-source.html which seems the output is limited to 1.5V?

Comment: I added a new image showing the op-amps in their conventional manner!

Comment: @JakeAdler There are a bunch of ways to make a constant current circuit. The simplest one uses only a single component: a depletion-mode FET such as a JFET.

Comment: @Hearth For reference: the goal of the circuit is a constant current waveform generator. Would that be possible with the JFET?

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question ^ still new to constant current sources

Comment: Read that whole app note, not just the first few paragraphs. What you're asking is discussed in their more clearly than you'll get explained here.

Comment: @Dionysus What is a "constant current waveform generator"? Are you sure you don't need a voltage-to-current converter of some sort?

Comment: Positive. Trying to build a device that can generate bi-phasic waveforms regardless of load impedance.

Answer (score 3):

I rely on the OP's claim that the circuit solution in question is an "improved Howland current source" and offer my explanation of the idea on which this famous circuit is built.

### The idea

We can figuratively call it "dynamic voltage source". In some (usually transistor) current source implementations, to keep the current constant, we vary a resistance RI connected in series to the load RL while keeping the supply voltage V constant. With the same success, we can vary the voltage V while keeping the resistance RI constant... i.e., to supply the RI-RL network by a "dynamic voltage source" (see Fig. *a* on the left below). For example, if RL increases its resistance, the voltage drop VL = I.RL across it will increase... but the voltage source will increase its voltage V with the same value... and the current I = V/(RI + RL) will not change. Figuratively speaking, the voltage increase removes the load resistance increase... as though it acts as equivalent negative resistance that removes the positive resistance increase.

[image: Dynamic voltage source]

### The implementation

An excellent implementation of this technique is the ingenious circuit solution of the so-called "improved Howland current pump" (Fig. *b* on the right above). Here the op-amp acts as the dynamic voltage source V which output voltage is "lifted" (by the inverting input) with the constant voltage VRI above the load voltage VL. The output voltage follows the variations of the load voltage VL by the mechanism of a positive feedback. The combination of the op-amp and the four resistors R can be thought as two cascaded circuits - the voltage divider on the right with ratio of R/(R + R) = 1/2 and the non-inverting amplifier on the left with gain of (R + R)/R = 2. Thus the total transfer ratio of the whole circuit is 1 and the load voltage variations (at the lower end of RI) appear at the op-amp output (at the upper end of RI). As a result, there is a constant voltage drop across the constant resistor RI; so the current through RI and RL is constant (does not depend on the load). The circuit can be thought as of a "shifted voltage follower" that behaves as a current source with extremely high differential internal resistance.

### Is there a negative feedback here?

Note, although there are two kinds of feedback - negative and positive, this current source does not use any feedback to keep the current constant... it is a current source without negative feedback. The circuit blindly corrects the input voltage without monitoring the final result - the load current. That is why, the resistances should be precise.

### Why two more op-amps?

Since I am mainly interested in circuit ideas, I work with conceptual circuit diagrams with symbolic notations of components. Because of this, the OP notations (with pin numbering) make it hard for me and I can only guess what it is. But still, my guess is that the two additional op-amps are buffer amplifiers that make the circuit more precise.

Maybe, the first op-amp is inserted between the input voltage source VREF (see my picture above) and the resistor of the inverting input; maybe, the second op-amp is connected between the load (RI-RL network) and the voltage divider of the non-inverting input.

### See also

You can see more about the philosophy behind current source implementations in my Codidact paper
[How to create current sources](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/279592). The *improved Howland current source* is considered in the section 5 figuratively named "Dynamic voltage source".

Also, in my circuit story [Widlar Op-Amp Current Source for Grounded Load](https://www.circuit-fantasia.com/circuit_stories/understanding_circuits/current_source/widlar_op-amp_current_source/widlar_op-amp_current_source.htm) I have visualized the circuit operation by voltage bars and current loops. I have named it after Widlar because I first saw it described by him (as a "bilateral current source") in his paper [IC Op Amp Beats FETs on Input Current](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/snoa624) in NSC's AN 29.

Comment: Hum ... As I have found, resistances don't need to be precise ... or equal. It is only a particular case. <<<The circuit blindly corrects the input voltage without monitoring the final result - the load current.>>> I should not say this, because it does "monitor" through my R5 (your R1).

Comment: @Antonio51, You made me begin thinking about this clever technique after so many years... My belief is that negative feedback is done with high voltage gain... but this idea can be done with a voltage follower... and [diode](https://www.circuit-fantasia.com/circuit_stories/understanding_circuits/current_source/transistor_source_diode/transistor_source_diode.htm)... or [capacitor](https://www.circuit-fantasia.com/circuit_stories/understanding_circuits/current_source/transistor_source_capacitor/transistor_source_capacitor.htm). I have to think...

Comment: Your codidact paper is incredible!

Comment: @Jake, thank you... But is it really? Then why hasn't anyone told me this, including the guy who created the Codidact EE site?

Comment: (might be sarcasm but if it's not) -> I'm a beginner and the language is very clear - b/c of availability bias I believe what you're writing is true but others may feel it's false(?) no idea.

Comment: @Dionysus, sorry for the mistake with your user name but I can't edit my comments above... OK, but if these guys feel this is not true they should still somehow react... but they are silent... How can this be explained? Perhaps through some psychological phenomenon? I can only guess...

Answer (score 1):

For [reference](https://sciendo.com/pdf/10.2478/joeb-2020-0014)
Sorry ... Replace "Hollow" with "Howland" ...
Here is what should be the current source behavior. R6 < 1 kOhm.

[image]

Your INA149 should be wired as this. It has internal "high-precision" resistors.
Check your wiring, especially OP145 (?) ... OPA277 seems ok for DAC bipolar output voltage.

Here is a Maple sheet for calculating the "transfer" function: ir6 vs V3.
Checking for V3 = -4 V. Also comparing to ir5 and iLoad (when G=infinity).
Note that ir5 and ir6 are quasi equal (if R6 << (R2+R4)).
Note also that if R6 << 2 R, i6 = - V3 / R5.

[image]

Here is an update of the Howland current source (modified for "nulling" offset, and for "correction" of the internal impedance which can be "positive" or "negative", to be checked in TRAN Analysis for stability).

[image]

**EDIT:** Added behavior of **R9** (**amp=-5 -> I=10 mA**) as asked in comment:
Schematic file [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dz9tha1h0xeh8o/Howland%20enh%20source%20current%20gen%20v0210.cir?dl=0), made with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm).
NB: **Inputs of INA149** can be swapped for "positive" function.

[image]

TRANsient Analysis for "stability" (step pulse with 1 us rise/fall time).

Setup time is about 4-5 us with LF13741.

[image]

And for another scale, just change R5 (25 Ohm), -> +/- 12 mA.

[image]

Setup time is, of course, longer, 7-8 us.

[image]

Comment: "Improved Howland current source"? It is interesting to see what the idea behind this famous circuit solution is...

Comment: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa436/sboa436.pdf?ts=1670601554951&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.be%252F#:~:text=The%20%E2%80%9CImproved%E2%80%9D%20Howland%20current%20pump,wide%20range%20of%20load%20resistance. With some "mistakes" about unit.

Comment: These produser's materials are so exhaustive of details and so helpless to show the (brilliantly) simple idea behind the circuit solution... Or maybe that's intentional?

Comment: Could you please add a bit answering the user's question, which is "how does the circuit work"?

Comment: AD8831 & OPA277 are used from the datasheet of AD8831 for bipolar output voltage. The INA149 is a very "high voltage" input amplifier (inside resistors are very well matched and needed for the Hollow current source). OPA145 has no "real" function (??? don't know) and at my thought ... not useful. I have redrawn the Hollow current source with the internal schematic of INA149 with an old good LF13741 (see update in answer).

Comment: Is it "Hollow" or "Howland"? Spell-checker mischief?

Comment: Yes, of course ... Sorry.

Comment: I'm pretty new to current sources so please don't mind the basic questions. Can you elaborate on the function of the potentiometer (connected to non-inv terminal of the INA149)?

Comment: The 750 Ohm potentiometer (adjusted value) makes it possible to make "horizontal" the curves of the figure i(R6) = f (R6). It therefore adjusts the internal (differential) impedance of the current source. If the potentiometer is incorrectly adjusted, the curves (almost horizontal) are either tilted up or down. I add a figure to show what happens to these curves.

Comment: @Dionysus  No worries. Added picture in answer: Q about 750 Ohm. Adding also schematic file and FREE simulator used.